# Strange Whitespace Error when Accessing RSS Feed

Tags: java, rss, whitespace, yahoo, feed

I'm not sure if anyone else has encountered or asked about this before, but for my application I make use of two Yahoo! RSS Feeds: Top News and Weather Forcast. I'm new to the idea of using these in the first place, but from what I've read, I simply need to make an HTTP GET request to a specific URL to retrieve an XML file which I can parse for the information I want. I have the parser working just fine, for I tested it with a sample XML file from each feed; however, a strange error is occuring when I use the AJAX GET call to the urls:

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

```
Whitespace is not allowed at this location. 
Error processing resource 'http://localhost:8080/BBS/fservlet?p=n'. Line 28, P...

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
-------------------^
```

Note that I have this applciation "BBS" currently deployed on my local system with Tomcat. I looked into whitespace errors like this, and most seem to point to some line within the XML file itself that's having a problem. In most cases, it had something to do with escaping the "&" symbol, but it appears as though IE is telling me that the error is within a for-loop. I'm no XML expert, but I've never seen a for-loop within an XML. Even so, I've gone to the url directly in my browser and viewed the XML file (its the one I used to test my parsing) and found no such line. In addition, no such loop exists anywhere in my code. In other words, I'm not sure if this is an error on my end, or some configuration setting. Here's the code I'm working with, however:

### jQuery Code

```
// Located in my JSP file
var baseContext = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
$(document).ready(function() {
    ParseWeather();
    ParseNews();
}

// Located in a separate JS file
function ParseWeather() {
    $.get(baseContext + "/servlet?p=w", function(data) {
        // XML Parser
    }
    // Data Manipulation
}

function ParseNews() {
    $.get(baseContext + "/servlet?p=n", function(data) {
        // XML Parser
    }
    // Data Manipulation
}
```

---

### Java Code

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.net.URL;

public class FeedServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            final URL url;
            String line = "";

            if(request.getParameter("p").equals("w")) {
                // Configuration setting that returns: "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=USOR0186"
                url = new URL(AppConfiguration.getInstance().getForcastUrl());
            } else {
                // Configuration setting that returns: "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/"
                url = new URL(AppConfiguration.getInstance().getNewsUrl());
            }
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
            final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.println(line);
                writer.flush();
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

My company has a AppConfiguration class that allows for certain variables, like the URL's, to be changed through the configuration page. At any rate, those two calls simple return the urls...

Yahoo! Forcast RSS Feed:
    http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=USOR0186

Yahoo! News: Top Stories Feed:
    http://news.yahoo.com/rss/

Anyway, any help would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: It looks like the requests to your servlet don't return the same data as the feeds. The Yahoo feeds don't contain that JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
> ```

The error is at the less-than symbol, which means that the XML parser is reading your source code! Use WGET to get the resource and check that actual XML is returned and not source code.